# Do Clearing slices in golang guarantees garbage collection?

Tags: go, garbage-collection, slice

I wanted to implement time based slots for holding data using golang slices. I managed to come up with a go program like this and it also works. But I have few questions regarding garbage collection and the general performance of this program. Does this program guarantee garbage collection of items once slice is equated to nil? And while shuffling slices, I hope this program does not do any deep copying.

```
type DataSlots struct {
    slotDuration  int //in milliseconds
    slots         [][]interface{}
    totalDuration int //in milliseconds
}

func New(slotDur int, totalDur int) *DataSlots {
    dat := &DataSlots{slotDuration: slotDur,
        totalDuration: totalDur}
    n := totalDur / slotDur
    dat.slots = make([][]interface{}, n)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        dat.slots[i] = make([]interface{}, 0)
    }
    go dat.manageSlots()
    return dat
}

func (self *DataSlots) addData(data interface{}) {
    self.slots[0] = append(self.slots[0], data)
}

// This should be a go routine
func (self *DataSlots) manageSlots() {
    n := self.totalDuration / self.slotDuration
    for {
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(self.slotDuration) * time.Millisecond)
        for i := n - 1; i > 0; i-- {
            self.slots[i] = self.slots[i-1]
        }
        self.slots[0] = nil
    }
}
```

I removed critical section handling in this snippet to make it concise.

Comment: How can `func (self *DataSlots) addData(data interface{})` be called? Their appears to be a potential 'race' between addData and manageSlots. Assuming New is always called to create instances of DataSlots, then there will be always be a manageSlots for every DataSlots. It looks like it can race with addData; `self.slots[0] = nil` vs `self.slots[0] = append(self.slots[0], data)`. Even then, the lost memory should be garbage collected.

Comment: Thanks. In my actual code, I do have this critical region mutex protected. Removed it here to make the code concise.

Comment: Okay. Might be worth adding a short comment to your question to say something about that; it is hard to read the code without noticing.

Comment: @gbulmer, edited the post.

Comment: Cool. IMHO protecting from the race condition isn't key to your question, so that should help without distracting anyone. Concise and complete !-)

Answer (score 5):

Once your slice is set too `nil`, any values contained in the slice are available for garbage collection, provided that the underlying array isn't shared with another slice.

Since there are no slice operations in your program, you never have multiple references to the same array, nor are you leaving data in any inaccessible portions of the underlying array.

What you need to be careful of, is when you're using slice operations:

```
a := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
b := a[1:3]
a = nil
// the values 1 and 4 can't be collected, because they are
// still contained in b's underlying array

c := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
c = append(c[1:2], 5)
// c is now []int{2, 5}, but again the values 1 and 4 are
// still in the underlying array. The 4 may be overwritten
// by a later append, but the 1 is inaccessible and won't
// be collected until the underlying array is copied.
```

While `append` does copy values when the capacity of the slice in insufficient, only the values contained in the slice are copied. There is no deep copy of any of the values.

Comment: Thanks. Answers my queries.